# Using CSS border-radius (rounded corners), how can we prevent the rounded corners from disappearing if the image is scaled down (max width/height)?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, width, border

Consider this scenario:

1. An image is centered both horizontally and vertically using a flex box
2. The image has a CSS border-radius configured (rounded corners)
3. The image is inside an `<a>` tag
4. The image is configured using CSS to take up no more than 50% of the horizontal or vertical space, and to shrink down proportionally if needed

```
<body style="margin:0;overflow:hidden;width:100%;height:100%;position:fixed;text-align:center;background-color:green">
  <div style="flex-direction:column;justify-content:center;align-items:center;display:flex;height:100vh;width:100%">
    <a href="https://google.com/" style="max-width:50%;max-height:50%">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/CHHOCY5.png" style="border-radius:20%;object-fit:scale-down;max-height:100%;max-width:100%;width:200px;height:200px">
    </a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Example:  https://jsfiddle.net/c8h0L7o1/

Normal operation (ample space available):

[image: Normal operation (ample space available):]

If available height and width are both reduced in roughly equal proportion, the rounded corners are retained as the image shrinks:

[image: If available height and width are both reduced in roughly equal proportion, the rounded corners are retained]

However if horizontal space is constrained but vertical space is not, or vice versa, the rounded corners are lost:

Vertical space constraint:

[image: vertical constraint]

Horizontal space constraint:

[image: horizontal constraint]

How can the rounded corners be retained in these scenarios?

The problem happens regardless if the border-radius is expressed in pixels or percent

Behavior has been verified in both Firefox and Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add border radius in anchor tag too

```
<a style="border-radius:20%" > img </a>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4s0neozL/ doesn't seem to make any difference as far as I can see

Comment: don't use width and height in image it make it's width relative to `<a>`

Comment: You mean like https://jsfiddle.net/btz7dpg2/ ?   Unfortunately vertical centering breaks when horizontal space is constrained https://i.imgur.com/RN1lw2k.png

Answer (score 1):

Delete `width:200px; height: 200px;` from img tag

Comment: and add `width: 200px; height: 200px;`  to the `<a></a>` tag

Comment: Seems to work but can you explain why? I'm having trouble understanding exactly what's happening here & why it didn't work the way I had it.

Comment: Without a height and width on the img tag, I'm a little concerned about the layout implications if the image doesn't load or something

Comment: I think that the `object-fit` style makes the image adapt to the dimensions of the `<a></a>` tag, thats why you have to place the `width=200px; height:200px` styles in the `<a></a>` tag instead of in the `<img/>`.

Comment: After further testing it seems like this breaks vertical alignment when horizontal space is constrained  https://jsfiddle.net/btz7dpg2/ https://i.imgur.com/RN1lw2k.png

Comment: seems to be adding the height to the anchor tag that causes issues... if I don't set the height anywhere, it seems to work okay (as long as the actual size of the image matches what I want the base height to be)  https://jsfiddle.net/gcs458fd/

Answer (score -1):

add class for img:

Then try to edit by CSS code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).